# Github Actions - Run job from input

Tags: github, github-actions

I'd like to be able to run a job based on job id provided from input, however it seems that the IF expression don't work (in job context) and I get both jobs running(in the example image below).

[Example code and pipeline run](https://i.stack.imgur.com/W0ajz.png)

Answer (score 2):

For what I tested [here](https://github.com/GuillaumeFalourd/poc-github-actions/blob/main/.github/workflows/workflow-tester7.yml), there are 2 points regarding what you want to achieve, that need to be evaluated.

#### First, the syntax you used for the `if` expression

`${{ github.event.inputs.job-name }} == {{ github.job }}`

Should be

`${{ github.event.inputs.job-name == github.job }}`

As if the expression contains any operators, the expression must be contained within `${{ }}` to explicitly mark it for evaluation ([reference](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/reference/workflow-syntax-for-github-actions#jobsjob_idif)).

#### Second, the job execution

It seems the if expression at the job level can't retrieve the `github.job` value. As with the correct syntax, it pulled both jobs:

[image]

In that case, a workaround could be to use the if expression at a step level, or use a `job` as premisse to check the context and then use other jobs with the `needs` field to perform each operation.

##### Example at the step level

```
  job-a:
    name: job-a
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
#    if: ${{ github.event.inputs.job-name == github.job }}
    steps:
    - name: Print something
      if: ${{ github.event.inputs.job-name == github.job }}
      run: |
        echo ${{ github.job }}
        echo ${{ github.event.inputs.job-name == github.job }}
        echo ${{ github.event.inputs.job-name }} ${{ github.job }}

  job-b:
    name: job-b
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
#    if: ${{ github.event.inputs.job-name == github.job }}
    steps:
    - name: Print something
      if: ${{ github.event.inputs.job-name == github.job }}
      run: |
        echo ${{ github.job }}
        echo ${{ github.event.inputs.job-name == github.job }}
        echo ${{ github.event.inputs.job-name }} ${{ github.job }}
```

Will return this with `job-a` **as input**, and won't execute the `job-b` step.

[image]

However, as I said above, if you *uncomment* the `if` at the job levels, the `job-a` and the `job-b` won't even be executed (image above).

Answer (score 2):

It can be done just at job-level as well. Useful when triggering manually and do not want to continuously comment/uncomment parts which you do not want to execute.
Just use the actual job name for matching instead of 'github.job'

```
name: Conditional job Selection based on input

on:      
  workflow_dispatch:
    inputs:
      job-name:
        description: 'Job id'
        required: true

jobs:
  build:
    name: build
    if: ${{ github.event.inputs.job-name == 'build' }}
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    
    steps:

    - uses: actions/checkout@v2
    
    - name: echo
      run: |
       echo "this is build job" 
     

    - name: Other steps 
      uses: actions/setup-java@v1
      with:
        java-version: '1.8'
         distribution: 'adopt'
        
  release:
    name: release
    if: ${{ github.event.inputs.job-name == 'release' }}
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    
    
    steps:
    - uses: actions/checkout@v2
    
    - name: echo
      run: |
       echo "this is release job" 
     

    - name: Other steps1
      uses: actions/setup-java@v1
      with:
        java-version: '1.8'
        distribution: 'adopt'
```